# Get session data in other page PHP MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, session

please note that im very new to php and mysql, i found login/register script on the internet and now im trying to figure things out, so my question is, how can i get user data from database and display it in other page? Please note that im using sessions.

Connection to database:

```
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');
```

Setting data upon registration:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO users (ip, username, email, password) 
                  VALUES('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
```

Full code can be found here:

```
<?php
session_start();

// initializing variables
$ip = "";
$username = "";
$email    = "";
$errors = array();

// connect to the database
$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'registration');


// REGISTER USER
if (isset($_POST['reg_user'])) {
  // receive all input values from the form
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['email']);
  $password_1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_1']);
  $password_2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password_2']);

  // form validation: ensure that the form is correctly filled ...
  // by adding (array_push()) corresponding error unto $errors array
  if (empty($username)) { array_push($errors, "Username is required"); }
  if (empty($email)) { array_push($errors, "Email is required"); }
  if (empty($password_1)) { array_push($errors, "Password is required"); }
  if ($password_1 != $password_2) {
    array_push($errors, "The two passwords do not match");
  }

  // first check the database to make sure
  // a user does not already exist with the same username and/or email
  $user_check_query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' OR email='$email' LIMIT 1";
  $result = mysqli_query($db, $user_check_query);
  $user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

  if ($user) { // if user exists
    if ($user['username'] === $username) {
      array_push($errors, "Username already exists");
    }

    if ($user['email'] === $email) {
      array_push($errors, "Email already exists");
    }
  }

  // Finally, register user if there are no errors in the form
  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password_1);//encrypt the password before saving in the database


    $query = "INSERT INTO users (ip, username, email, password)
              VALUES('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '$username', '$email', '$password')";
    mysqli_query($db, $query);

    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
    header('location: index.php');
  }
}

// ...
// ...

// LOGIN USER
if (isset($_POST['login_user'])) {
  $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['username']);
  $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['password']);

  if (empty($username)) {
    array_push($errors, "Username is required");
  }
  if (empty($password)) {
    array_push($errors, "Password is required");
  }

  if (count($errors) == 0) {
    $password = md5($password);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'";
    $results = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($results) == 1) {


      $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
      $_SESSION['success'] = "You are now logged in";
      header('location: index.php');
    }else {
        array_push($errors, "Wrong username or password combination");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to include `session_start();` at the top of every PHP page. If you don't, the session will be destroyed and the user is logged out. If you wish to display the username, you can use `echo $_SESSION['username'];` on any page that has `session_start():` because you've set that one up here: `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`. If you wish to display more data, you either need to save that in other session variables or query your database with a `SELECT` query on the page where you wish to display it.

Comment: On a side note: Stop using `mysqli_real_escape_string();` and start using [MySQLi Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php). Because escaping doesn't protect you from SQL injection. Also: Make sure you include _all relevant code_ in your question. Don't post it somewhere else and link to it. If you do that, the post might get lost at some point and your question becomes unreadable for others in the future.

Comment: Your script is wide open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's

Comment: Please dont __roll your own__ password hashing, specially not using MD5() or SHA1(). PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them.
And here are some [good ideas about passwords](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet)
If you are using a PHP version prior to 5.5 [there is a compatibility pack available here](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Heh; OP's using MD5, not plain text ;-)

Comment: @RiggsFolly *Sweet!*

Comment: Thanks for Your time @icecub, "If you wish to display more data, you either need to save that in other session variables" i feel like this is what im going for, how should i do that?

Comment: Just add `$_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];`, `$_SESSION['email'] = $email;` etc underneath `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;`. After that you can call them the same way as the username.

Comment: @icecub, for some reason I can only get a username and a password, email and ip appears blank.

Comment: Well then you have to figure out why. I can't see that from here. Appearently those variables don't contain a value. It's up to you to find out why

Comment: @Funky Forty Niner; MD5 is way to weak for use as a password hashing algorithm as with modern computing power it can be cracked too easily and AFAIK has been rainbow tabled to death